# unable to find installed GAC in c:\windows\assembly

Tags: c#, dll, gac

i have installed a dll using the commands below

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0>gacutil.exe /i "C:\temp\ContosoProviders.dll"
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.33440
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Assembly successfully added to the cache

i was unable to find the named GAC in the c:\windows\assembly

however when i use "C:\assemblyinfo.txt", i was able to find the name of the assembly inside. is the assembly installed properly?

Answer (score 1):

From `.NET Framework 4.0` and higher assemblies started to be stored in a different physical location which is:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly
```

You might find your dll there